# Is the verb in 受話器から変な音がして止まらない future tense?

Tags: grammar

> 受話器から変な音がして止まらない。
>
> Strange noises keep coming from the receiver and won't stop.

"Won't" in this case is closer to "desire, choice,willingness, consent, or in negative constructions refusal" and isn't really future tense. Is Japanese similar in this case?

Comment: It doesn't seem real future tense either.

Answer (score 3):

The てform of して here is acting as a way to join the two clauses.

> 変な音がする and 止まらない

The 止まらない is nothing special. Just the negative tense of 止まる so we can interpret it as **don't/won't stop**. There is no element of "desire, choice, willingness, consent."

Answer (score 0):

”The door is stuck on something and won't budge.”

> Strange noises keep coming from the receiver and won't stop.

The verb [will] here (i think) is not future...

It's mostly

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/will --   To wish, desire

```
            It's odd that this page says "rare" usage.
```

> 受話器から変な音がして止まろうとしない。

A bit of anthropomorphism . . . to me, it sounds Murakami Haruki -ish.